# Using Spring Data Projection on DBRef objects

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb

I'm starting to learn Spring Data on a pretty simple project using a MongoDB database, and I'm having some trouble when using DBRef - and maybe in how to model a NoSQL db in general

### Description

My project should organize a simple competition with a organizer (CD) and one-to-many participants. Because people can participate in multiple competitions I made respositories for both Competition and Person.

The complete code can be seen on GitHub : https://github.com/elkjaerit/rest-sample

Here is the base classes:

```
public class Competition {

  @Id private String id;

  private String name;

  @DBRef
  private Person organizer;

  private List<Participant> participants = new ArrayList<>();

}


public class Participant {

  private String freq;

  @DBRef
  private Person person;
}


public class Person {
  @Id
  private String id;

  private String name;
}
```

Repositories:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "competition", path = "competition")
public interface CompetitionRepository extends MongoRepository<Competition, String> {

}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "person", path = "person")
public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {

}
```

### Problem

When I'm requesting a competition resource I'm not getting enough info on the participants - only "freq" field is shown. I've tried using @Projection and managed to get it to work for the organizer but I don't know how to get the person object for the participant ?

#### Result without projection

```
{
"_links": {
    "competition": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/competition/5710b32b03641c32671f885a{?projection}", 
        "templated": true
    }, 
    "organizer": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/competition/5710b32b03641c32671f885a/organizer"
    }, 
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/competition/5710b32b03641c32671f885a"
    }
}, 
"name": "Competition #1", 
"participants": [
    {
        "freq": "F0"
    }, 
    {
        "freq": "F1"
    }, 
    {
        "freq": "F2"
    }, 
    {
        "freq": "F3"
    }
]
}
```

#### And with projection

```
{
"_links": {
    "competition": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/competition/5710b32b03641c32671f885a{?projection}", 
        "templated": true
    }, 
    "organizer": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/competition/5710b32b03641c32671f885a/organizer"
    }, 
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/competition/5710b32b03641c32671f885a"
    }
}, 
"name": "Competition #1", 
"organizer": {
    "name": "Competition organizer"
}, 
"participants": [
    {
        "freq": "F0"
    }, 
    {
        "freq": "F1"
    }, 
    {
        "freq": "F2"
    }, 
    {
        "freq": "F3"
    }
]
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use SPEL to call the getter for your related documents.

Your projection may look something like this -

```
    @Projection(name = "comp", types = {Competition.class})
public interface CompetitionProjection {

    String getName();

    Person getOrganizer();

    @Value("#{target.getParticipants()}")
    List<Participant> getParticipants();
}
```